# Constructing elements that meet order requirements in finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $n$ be an integer.  Construct a group $G$ containing two elements $a$ and $b$ of order 2 whose product is of order $n$.

My attempt at a solution:

If we have that $n$ is a number such that $n-1$ is going to be prime.  We can pretty easily just take the set $\mathbb{Z}/(n-1)\mathbb{Z}$ and we can find that as $n-1$ is going to be prime, there is going to be two elements $a$ and $b$ that fit this request.  However, it's fairly difficult (or I found) to explicitly write those two elements down.

Is there any way to generalize it into the case that was needed?

This is from a practise final, so just any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You will not find your example in an abelian group, because in such group if $a,b$ are of order $2$, then so is $ab$.

Answer (score 0):

In the dihedral group, the product of two reflections is a rotation.  More specifically, in $D_{2n}$, the product of $s$ and $sr$ (each of order $2$) is $r$, an element of order $n$, where $r$ and $s$ are the usual generators in the presentation
$$ D_{2n} = \langle r, s \mid r^n = s^2 = 1, \, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle. $$